# How use MailKit's ImapClient.Authenticate with umlaut in password?

Tags: imap, mailkit

I'm calling the MailServer.Authenticate(string, string) method on an ImapClient and using ä (lowercase a-umlaut) as a password.  This fails with the protocol log below.  Using Authenticate(encoding, string, string) with UTF-8 encoding fails in the same way (I've also tried UTF-7 and iso-8859-1 without success).

```
S: * OK IMAPrev1
C: A00000000 CAPABILITY
S: * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN IDLE QUOTA SORT ACL NAMESPACE RIGHTS=texk
S: A00000000 OK CAPABILITY completed
C: A00000001 LOGIN tester2@test.com {2}
S: + Ready for additional command text.
C: ä
S: A00000001 NO Invalid user name or password.
C: A00000002 LOGOUT
S: * BYE Have a nice day
S: A00000002 OK Logout completed
```

The server is hMailServer, which I'm able to contact and retrieve messages from using Thunderbird.  Below is hMailServer's log for the failed attempt from my MailKit application, followed by the successful authentication at the start of a Thunderbird session.  Is there any way I can authenticate with a password which contains accented charaters?

```
"DEBUG" 14744   "2021-02-04 09:40:59.274"   "TCP connection started for session 2"
"IMAPD" 14744   2   "2021-02-04 09:40:59.275"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: * OK IMAPrev1"
"IMAPD" 21360   2   "2021-02-04 09:40:59.302"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: A00000000 CAPABILITY"
"IMAPD" 21360   2   "2021-02-04 09:40:59.303"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN IDLE QUOTA SORT ACL NAMESPACE RIGHTS=texk[nl]A00000000 OK CAPABILITY completed"
"IMAPD" 11636   2   "2021-02-04 09:40:59.324"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: A00000001 LOGIN tester2@test.com ***"
"IMAPD" 11636   2   "2021-02-04 09:40:59.325"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: + Ready for additional command text."
"IMAPD" 21360   2   "2021-02-04 09:40:59.327"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: ***"
"IMAPD" 21360   2   "2021-02-04 09:40:59.331"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: A00000001 NO Invalid user name or password."
"IMAPD" 11636   2   "2021-02-04 09:40:59.379"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: A00000002 LOGOUT"
"IMAPD" 11636   2   "2021-02-04 09:40:59.380"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: * BYE Have a nice day[nl]A00000002 OK Logout completed"
"DEBUG" 21360   "2021-02-04 09:40:59.381"   "Ending session 2"

"DEBUG" 14744   "2021-02-04 09:41:43.613"   "TCP connection started for session 5"
"IMAPD" 14744   5   "2021-02-04 09:41:43.614"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: * OK IMAPrev1"
"IMAPD" 21360   5   "2021-02-04 09:41:43.616"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: 1 capability"
"IMAPD" 21360   5   "2021-02-04 09:41:43.616"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN IDLE QUOTA SORT ACL NAMESPACE RIGHTS=texk[nl]1 OK CAPABILITY completed"
"IMAPD" 11636   5   "2021-02-04 09:41:43.618"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: 3 login "tester2@test.com" ***"
"IMAPD" 11636   5   "2021-02-04 09:41:43.620"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 3 OK LOGIN completed"
"IMAPD" 11636   5   "2021-02-04 09:41:43.625"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: 4 capability"
"IMAPD" 11636   5   "2021-02-04 09:41:43.626"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN IDLE QUOTA SORT ACL NAMESPACE RIGHTS=texk[nl]4 OK CAPABILITY completed"
"IMAPD" 21360   5   "2021-02-04 09:41:43.628"   "127.0.0.1" "RECEIVED: 5 select "INBOX""
"DEBUG" 21360   "2021-02-04 09:41:43.629"   "Reading messages from database."
"IMAPD" 21360   5   "2021-02-04 09:41:43.630"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: * 6 EXISTS[nl]* 2 RECENT[nl]* FLAGS (\Deleted \Seen \Draft \Answered \Flagged)[nl]* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1612370073] current uidvalidity[nl]* OK [UIDNEXT 7] next uid[nl]* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Deleted \Seen \Draft \Answered \Flagged)] limited[nl]5 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed"
```

Comment: The LOGIN command defines ASCII as encoding, so you shouldn't use ä with it. AUTHENTICATE PLAIN [explicitly uses UTF-8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4616.html#section-2) so ä is well-defined.

Comment: @arnt Thanks.  So I guess Thunderbird and hMailServer are being liberal in their conformance to the protocol specification with regard to the LOGIN command.  My task now is to figure out how to get hMailServer to advertise and accept SASL AUTHENTICATE PLAIN

Comment: Support for AUTHENTICATE PLAIN is required by the base specification (see the bottom two lines of page 28); it doesn't need to be separately advertised. I suggest that you raise a bug for Thunderbird and say that it should send AUTHENTICATE PLAIN rather than LOGIN when the password isn't all-ASCII, and mention interop with hMailServer as a practical effect of the bug.

Comment: It looks like Thunderbird doesn’t bother with the command continuation.  It could be hmailserver has a bug in the command continuation or does not actually support it for login.  Can you force ImapClient not to use command continuation?

Comment: According to the hMailServer source code, it looks like there must be a config option to enable AUTH=PLAIN: https://github.com/hmailserver/hmailserver/blob/master/hmailserver/source/Server/IMAP/IMAPCommandCapability.cpp#L39 - also worth noting that unless this string appears in the CAPABILITY response, it won't work in the AUTHENTICATE command (which also checks this option)